# Powershell StreamReader, make variable from each rreadline

Tags: powershell, csv, streamreader

I am trying to write a script that will split a very large CSV (1 million rows) into 100 csv's. I am using StreamReader rather than import as the file is so big.
I have started the code:

```
$src = "c:\TestCSV.csv"
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($src)
$header = Get-Content -Path $src | select -First 1

while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null){
$data = $line -Split ','
$NiNumber = $data[9]
$Char6 = $NiNumber.Substring(6,1);
$Char7 = $NiNumber.Substring(7,1);
$Group = $Char6 + $Char7
Write-Host "▸▸ Adding Line to Group  $Group " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
$stream =[System.IO.StreamWriter] "c:\test$Group.csv"
$stream.WriteLine($line)
$stream.Close()
Write-Host -Object '✔' -ForegroundColor green
}
$reader.Close()
```

My CSV has 13 columns with headers, I am getting the group number from the 9th column by sub stringing. I then need to output all lines to a new CSV with that group name. This works for 1 line, but it doesn't seem to add any more lines to a CSV. (not sure if it just creates a new CSV and overwrites the existing one). 
Could anybody help me to finish this, so that it adds multiple lines to a csv, also if possible add the headers to each csv? any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear it, you should also post your solution.  Although I'm not sure there is actually a question here.

Comment: HI Jim sorry new to this site, I added a comment prematurely, although I have progressed to now get each line out put to a CSV it doesn't add multiple lines but rather seems to create a new file each time regardless of if it already exists, so overwrites any existing files. which means all CSV files only have one row in them.

Comment: John, I think you need to make your question clearer, I'm not sure what you are asking for.  It would also be useful to post a sample of the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix the overwrite issue by changing the way I called the streamwriter and appending $true.

```
$src = "c:\TestCSV.csv"
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($src)
$header = Get-Content -Path $src | select -First 1
while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null){
$data = $line -Split ','
$NiNumber = $data[9]
$Char6 = $NiNumber.Substring(6,1);
$Char7 = $NiNumber.Substring(7,1);
$Group = $Char6 + $Char7
Write-Host "▸▸ Adding Line to Group  $Group " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
$GroupPath = "c:\test$Group.csv"
$stream = New-Object IO.StreamWriter($GroupPath,$true)
$stream.WriteLine($line)
$stream.Close()
Write-Host -Object '✔' -ForegroundColor green
}
$reader.Close()
```

Comment: If size/time is an issue, why use 3 commands instead of one to get the $group ? `$Group = $NiNumber.Substring(6,2)`

Comment: Great @John. Congratulations on your first 10 pointer. I really loved the approach you made.

Comment: Ah good point! I was so focused on the end goal I didn't even think to use one variable instead of 2, doh! I ran the code on the whole document and left it running over night and it worked well.